# How do I bind kind and field name as well as properties?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I need to use bound properties that include the kind and field name (to make a generic API call) e.g. from the unbound:

```
q = ndb.gql("SELECT __key__ FROM kind WHERE fruit = 'apple' ")
```

I'd like it be end up with three bindings, e.g.

```
q = ndb.gql("SELECT __key__ FROM :1 WHERE :2 = :3", 'kind', 'fruit', 'apple')
```

Happy not to use GQL if it can be done by the ndb query methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we won't use the same way to bind kind and field name.

> Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.

```
q = ndb.gql("SELECT __key__ FROM %s WHERE %s = :1" %( 'kind', 'fruit'), 'apple')
```